# Select elements which don't have parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$("#result").html($('[contenteditable]').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="scorer">
  <div>
    <div contenteditable>1</div>
    <div contenteditable>2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div contenteditable>3</div>
  <div contenteditable>4</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div id="result">
  result
</div>
```

How can I select contenteditable elements which do not have a parent up the chain of "scorer" in CSS or jquery.

Result should be 34.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `not()` function like this `.not('.scorer div')`

```js
$("#result").html($('[contenteditable]').not('.scorer div').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="scorer">
  <div>
    <div contenteditable>1</div>
    <div contenteditable>2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div contenteditable>3</div>
  <div contenteditable>4</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div id="result">
  result
</div>
```

Comment: In addition to that you can also use :not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter function for this

```
var result = $("div[contenteditable]").filter(function () {
    return $(this).closest(".scorer").length == 0
}).text();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/99/)

Answer (score 1):

Try `not()`

```
$("#result").html($('[contenteditable]').parent().not('.scorer div').text());
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/beera/Lv5cn8xy/102/)

Comment: @vineeth, actually your code is not returning the contenteditable divs,rather it returns the parent element.  see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/104/

Answer (score 1):

Try to fetch all except for children of scorer:

```
$('div[contenteditable]').not('.scorer div');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you a different approach which is the one i find more easier to read

```
$('.result').html($('div:not(.scorer) [contenteditable]').text());
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MatsKruger/c2gjjgbw/)